# Having difficulty connecting to PostgreSQL with Django hosted on IIS

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2016, python, django, iis-10

Trying to host Django 4 app with PostgreSQL database on Windows Server 2016 with IIS manager 10 and httpPlatformHandler 1.2.

The app and database work without issues when running on a VM server with `python manage.py runserver` in cmd. The problem comes when trying to access with IIS, the Log file shows:

```
    psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: :1), port 23825                failed: could not receive data from server: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
```

and after I changed DB address from localhost ot 127.0.0.1 the error changed to

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\psycopg\connection.py", line 729, in connect
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: could not receive data from server: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
```

and sometimes

```
psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: could not receive data from server: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
```

I think there is some option in IIS that prevents establishing a connection.

Comment: How does the connection string look like?

Comment: @LexLi I use Django settings for psycopg3, is the connection string something else? Host=127.0.0.1 and port=5432, it works fine in a standalone process.

Comment: Found a similar question: [issue-when-running-django-site-on-iis-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336754/issue-when-running-django-site-on-iis-server)

Comment: So if you only specified host and port, you intend to use SSPI authentication? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sspi-auth.html

Comment: @LexLi No I have user and password also

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so, you may want to Update your "pg_hba.conf" File, to Allow Connections from Localhost, over IPv4 and IPv6.

```
#TYPE  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS       METHOD
 host  all       all   127.0.0.1/32  trust
 host  all       all   localhost     trust
 host  all       all   ::1/128       trust
```

You can find additional information here.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Still same error